# "neueingeführt" versus "neu eingeführt"

Tags: adjective, spelling

Ich mag mich erinnern, das Substantiv "Neueinführung" gelegentlich gelesen zu haben. Wie aber schreibt man hierzu das Adjektiv? Zusammen, getrennt oder gar mit Bindestrich?

> Eine neueingeführte Technologie

oder:

> Eine neu eingeführte Technologie

oder gar:

> Eine neu-eingeführte Technologie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Kurzantwort

Alle drei Varianten sind erlaubt, die Version mit Bindestrich ist aber mit großer Vorsicht zu genießen.

---

### In Detail

Gerade bei Adjektiven, die man auch als Partizipien von Verben interpretieren kann, findet man viele Beispiele, bei denen *»neu-«* als Vorsilbe hinzugefügt werden kann:

In der folgenden Liste stehen:

1. Zuerst das Verb
2. Dann das Partizip II, das auch als Adjektiv interpretiert werden kann
3. Am Ende das Adjektiv, das durch Hinzufügen der Vorsilbe *neu-* entsteht.

> - gebären - geboren - neugeboren
> - gründen - gegründet - neugegründet
> - gestalten - gestaltet - neugestaltet
> - schaffen - geschaffen - neugeschaffen
> - gewinnen - gewonnen - neugewonnen
> - entstehen - entstanden - neuentstanden
> - gestalten - gestaltet - neugestaltet
> - erscheinen - erschienen - neuerschienen
> - zulassen - zugelassen - neuzugelassen
> - ankommen - angekommen - neuangekommen
> - aufnehmen - aufgenommen - neuaufgenommen

Es gibt aber auch Verben, an die direkt die Vorsilbe *neu-* angefügt werden kann (der häufigere Fall sind aber die oben beschriebenen Partizipien):

> - bauen - neubauen
> - formieren - neuformieren
> - gestalten - neugestalten
> - schreiben - neuschreiben
>     usw.

In einigen Fällen haben bereits die Verben selbst (und damit auch die Partizipien) eine Vorsilbe (*an-kommen, auf-nehmen,* ...). Durch Anfügen von *ein-* entsteht dann eben ein Wort mit zwei Vorsilben, das ist nichts ungewöhnliches.

Dabei kann natürlich auch die Kombination *»neu- + ein-«* auftreten, wie in diesen Fällen:

> - neueingerichtet
> - neueingestellt
> - neueingesetzt

und daher selbstverständlich auch:

> - **neueingeführt**

---

Nachdem nun geklärt ist, dass die Zusammenschreibung erlaubt ist, kann man daraus auch gleich schlussfolgern, dass auch die Schreibung mit Bindestrich in bestimmten Fällen erlaubt ist, wenngleich sie keineswegs empfohlen wird.

Die Schreibweise

> neu-eingeführt

ist nämlich nur dann erlaubt, wenn der Teil *neu-* ganz besonders hervorgehoben werden soll; wenn also z.B. im Text ausdrücklich hervorgehoben werden soll, dass die Technologie nicht einfach nur ganz normal eingeführt wurde, sondern dass es sich um neu-eingeführte Technologie handelt (worin auch immer dieser Unterschied bestehen mag).

Wäre die Zusammenschreiben (*neueingeführt*) unzulässig, so wäre auch die Form mit Bindestrich falsch.

---

Davon völlig unabhängig ist die getrennte Schreibweise:

Im Deutschen ist das Leerzeichen als Konkatenierungszeichen nicht vorgesehen. Die *»Ferien Insel«* ist daher falsch, ein solcherart verwendetes Leerzeichen wird umgangssprachlich gerne mal als »Deppen-Leerzeichen« bezeichnet.

Bei *»neu eingeführt«* liegt aber gar keine Konkatenierung vor. Das sind einfach nur zwei voneinander unabhängige Wörter, die nur aufgrund ihrer Position im Satz einen grammatischen Bezug zueinander haben (*»neu«* ist ein Attribut von *»eingeführt«*), ohne deswegen gemeinsam als eigenständiger Begriff angesehen zu werden.

Das heißt: Die Schreibweise

> neu eingeführt

ist vollkommen richtig.

---

### Fazit

Alle drei Schreibweisen sind erlaubt, wobei man aber von der Schreibweise mit Bindestrich nur in ganz besonderen Fällen Gebrauch machen sollte, und nur, wenn man ganz genau weiß, was man tut.

Die beiden Schreibweisen

> 1. die neueingeführte Technologie
> 2. die neu eingeführte Technologie

sind beide bedenkenlos verwendbar.

Comment: Herzlichen Dank! Besser hätte man es nicht ausführen können